# DataSource attribute causing Unit Test to be skipped

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

Just out of curiosity has anyone ever had the issues of a test being skipped only when the DataSource attribute is enabled on that specific test. When I try to run this specific test, Test Explorer consistently shows **ExecuteSproc_Test ignored** with no meaning or explanation. Examples below

***Works***

```
public TestContext testContext { get; set; }
[TestMethod]
//[DataSource("SqlClient","ConnectionString","SqlTable", Sequential)]
public void ExecuteSproc_Test()
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(testContext.DataRow["Row"]);
}
```

***Ignored***

```
public TestContext testContext { get; set; }
[TestMethod]
[DataSource("SqlClient","ConnectionString","SqlTable", Sequential)]
public void ExecuteSproc_Test()
{
    Assert.IsNotNull(testContext.DataRow["Row"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem doing that. For example, Microsoft's documentation does this in an example on the page  [How To: Create a Data-Driven Unit Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx).

So my guess would be that your DataSource isn't returning any rows.